# How should I handle questions about forgotten credentials

Tags: discussion, flagging, closed-questions, moderators

I have a problem how to handle the 99% new users with questions how to crack a password, or AppleID, in some cases forgotten recovery email, or claiming the email is no longer in use.

The questions vary from system log in password, iPhone, iCloud, Firmware password an so on.

Since there is no way to verify it is the rightful owner, I hesitate to provide information.

Should one use "Close" or "Flag" or am I just paranoid, or should I try to help how to.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of reasons why people loose access to their computers, most of them are legitimate. So unless there is a clear indication that something is amiss, these questions are perfectly on-topic and can be answered, often easily by referring the user to the appropriate Apple Support pages or by finding the duplicate question which already has been answered before.

Please keep in mind that we are not the police or so, so there is no way to verify the story/background of a question anyway. If in doubt, flag it and move on.

Comment: Also if there is a way of doing this other people should be taught about it so that we know where there is a security risk - security by obscurity does not work well